# How to installing Pygame for Python 3.5 via pip?

Tags: pygame, pip, python-3.5

I'm trying to install Pygame for python 3.5 32bit. I have learned that I can open the `.whl` files provided on the site by using the `pip` command. The problem is I've tried multiple ways doing this but with constant error.

```
python -m pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl

'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The file I'm trying to install: `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl`

My python program is located in my programs folder and everything else works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to add *python.exe* to your *Windows `PATH` variable*.**

The is the system variable that the operating system uses to locate the needed executables from the command line or Terminal windows. [[1]](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

---

Actually there are many methods to **set the `PATH` variable on windows**. One way is to type

`set PATH=%PATH%;`*location path of `Python.exe`*

into the windows command-line interpreter (cmd):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python35-32
```

---

Now -- before running the `pip command` -- you need to make sure that either

- your [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is set to the same folder where your `pygame-1. ... in32.whl` file is located

  or
- you supply the full absolute or relative path to the `pip` command.

Now you should be able to run your `python -m pip` command after restarting the `cmd.exe`.

Comment: The set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python35-32 went into the command without any errors but nothing seems to have changed. Opening the file location to python 3.5 it's located in a bunch of folders, through C:/users/EliCruz/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/windows/start menu/programs/Python 3.5   could this be an issue?

Comment: I reinstalled Python 3.5 and check marked the path this time which fixed that but now I'm being told the file im trying to install doesn't exist when its in the python 3.5 folder

Comment: GOT IT! lol pulled it out of the folder and put it into the my user EliCruz and everything works! whew, thanks for the help :]

Answer (score 1):

if you get trouble when install pygame error about missing visual studio 10+. I have the answer: the problem is not about have or not have visual studio, because I try many version but it not work. The problem is file: between tar.gz and .whl so, this is the solution:

1) download file:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame go here and download your pygame version, notice about x64 or x86 and python version. my system is x64 and python is 3.4 so I choose: pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl

2) put it in some where to install:

I put it in "C:", so open cmd: and type: `cd C:\` (this changes the location to C:)

3) install

```
pip install C:\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

done !