# Unable install pygame on Python 3.5 on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pygame

I tried to install in a lot of ways the pygame module for python 3.5 but I just got errors.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried searching for any of those errors? `The system cannot find the path specified.` is a very common one on Windows, and is _definitely_ documented on this site.

Comment: I prefer you to read the answer by elegent over here ~~~> [How to installing Pygame for Python 3.5 via pip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126957/how-to-installing-pygame-for-python-3-5-via-pip)

Answer (score 1):

First figure out if you have a 32 or 64 bit Python version and download the corresponding whl (wheel) file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. When I start Python it prints `[MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]` (that's the 64 bit version).

Then navigate to the directory that contains the Pygame .whl file and enter `py -3.5 -m pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl` if you have a 32 bit Python or `py -3.5 -m pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` if you have the 64 bit version.